# Any similar function like ubuntu software center in Kubuntu?

Tags: kubuntu

I am trying out Kubuntu 11.04 and I am a total newbie for linux. I played ubuntu before but didn't really like its setup. However, I did find Software Center is very convenience tool but I couldn't find the similar function in Kubuntu. Now I can't even install Flash Player...:(.. Any helps? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Muon Package Management Suite](http://jontheechidna.wordpress.com/2010/12/04/muon-is-now-the-muon-package-management-suite/):

1. The Muon Package Manager. (Which has heretofore been called “Muon”) Its focus has been and will remain hardcore package management with a sane GUI.
2. The Muon Updater, an update manager
3. Finally and with grand introduction, The Muon Software Center.

Synaptic Package Manager will be dropped as the default in the next development of Ubuntu (Oneiric 11.10) and this package manager will be shipped out.

However you can always install the Software Center ('Ubuntu Software Center') as it is available to install in Kubuntu from the default repositories.

Comment: whoa how did i miss the muon software centre! thanks!